# runtime '-2147417848(90010108)' : Insert method of Range class failed while insert range

Tags: excel, vba

When only I execute the code below it is correct. But if I delete some blank rows in the worksheet and execute the code again, I will get

> error runtime '-2147417848(90010108)' : Insert method of Range class
> failed.

where is the problem? This has troubled me for a long time, can anyone give me some help, thanks.
Forgive my poor English.

```
Dim desWorkbook As Workbook 
Set desWorkbook = Application.ThisWorkbook
Dim desWorksheet As Worksheet
Set desWorksheet = desWorkbook.Worksheets("A")
Dim srcWorkbook As Workbook 
Set srcWorkbook = Workbooks.Open("D:\src.xlsx", False)
Dim srcWorksheet As Worksheet 
Set srcWorksheet = srcWorkbook.Worksheets("A")
Dim srcRange As Range
Set srcRange = srcWorksheet.Range("A2:AQ100") 
srcRange.Copy
desWorksheet.Range("3:3").Insert Shift:=xlDown 'error is here
```

Comment: Is the worksheet protected?  If Yes then you need to first unprotect it.

Comment: Sheet is not protected. :-(

Comment: Inserting rows can also fail if there's content (or sometimes formatting) on the last row of the sheet, but you would have seen a different error message for that...

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, but I tried pressing Ctrl+Shift+down and clearing all before executing the code, and the error still appears. Could this be an Excel bug? I use office 2013.If I don't delete rows before executing the code, everything is correct.

Comment: Do you have any event handlers in that worksheet module (or at the workbook level)?

Comment: only this one sub...

Comment: After it has failed, try executing `Debug.Print desWorksheet.UsedRange.Address` and see what you get.

Comment: If the execution result is correct, desWorksheet.UsedRange.Address is $A$1:$AQ$196.
If the execution result is wrong, the address is $A$1:$AQ$xxx, and xxx is different each time. I'm guessing it might have something to do with the number of blank lines I removed.

Comment: I’m out of guesses